# c# Tic Toc Tow determin draw

Tags: c#

Hey I have been working with coding for 4 weeks or so, and i'm now trying to do a tic toc tow game.
I have made it so far that I can play the game and find the winner. I'm a bit stuck on how to determin a draw when all 9 spaces are full.

I also need the game to stop when the winner is found. in other words it should be impossible to put another piece when the winner is found.

If anyone could help with some of it, then it will be awesome!

Here are my not so friendly code for to determin a winner.

```
// check rows
        if (GameBoard[0, 0] == 'X' && GameBoard[0, 1] == 'X' && GameBoard[0, 2] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[1, 0] == 'X' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'X' && GameBoard[1, 2] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[2, 0] == 'X' && GameBoard[2, 1] == 'X' && GameBoard[2, 2] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }

        // check columns
        if (GameBoard[0, 0] == 'X' && GameBoard[1, 0] == 'X' && GameBoard[2, 0] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[0, 1] == 'X' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'X' && GameBoard[2, 1] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[0, 2] == 'X' && GameBoard[1, 2] == 'X' && GameBoard[2, 2] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }

        // check diags
        if (GameBoard[0, 0] == 'X' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'X' && GameBoard[2, 2] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[0, 2] == 'X' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'X' && GameBoard[2, 0] == 'X') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 1 You won! GG"; }





        // check rows
        if (GameBoard[0, 0] == 'O' && GameBoard[0, 1] == 'O' && GameBoard[0, 2] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[1, 0] == 'O' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'O' && GameBoard[1, 2] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[2, 0] == 'O' && GameBoard[2, 1] == 'O' && GameBoard[2, 2] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }

        // check columns
        if (GameBoard[0, 0] == 'O' && GameBoard[1, 0] == 'O' && GameBoard[2, 0] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[0, 1] == 'O' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'O' && GameBoard[2, 1] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[0, 2] == 'O' && GameBoard[1, 2] == 'O' && GameBoard[2, 2] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }

        // check diags
        if (GameBoard[0, 0] == 'O' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'O' && GameBoard[2, 2] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }
        if (GameBoard[0, 2] == 'O' && GameBoard[1, 1] == 'O' && GameBoard[2, 0] == 'O') { message = "Winner winner chicen dinner Player 2 You won! GG"; }
```

Comment: Looks like you're really enjoying it - next up then a sodoku solver :) you get to take the principal of here and scale it up :)

Comment: Maybe a draw is if neither player is a winner and no legal moves remain?

Answer (score 2):

Well you've done a good job so far, it seems what you're missing is the use of functions. For instance you can define a function to check a single row:

```
bool SingleRowComplete(int rowNum, char player) {
    return GameBoard[rowNum, 0] == player && GameBoard[rowNum, 1] == player && GameBoard[rowNum, 2] == player;
}
```

Then we can create a wrapper function:

```
bool AnyRowComplete(char player) {
return SingleRowComplete(0, player) || SingleRowComplete(1, player) || SingleRowComplete(2, player);
}
```

You can create similar functions for column and the main diagonals.

Once those are down you check then encapsulate:

```
bool PlayerWon(char player) {
return AnyRowComplete(player) || AnyColumnComplete(player) || AnyDiagonalComplete(player);
}
```

I guess as a final point i'll say good job, and now to learn functions :)

Comment: `bool AnyRowComplete(char player) {
return AnyRowComplete(0, player) || SingleRowComplete(1, player) || SingleRowComplete(2, player)
}`



should be



`bool AnyRowComplete(char player) {
return SingleRowComplete(0, player) || SingleRowComplete(1, player) || SingleRowComplete(2, player)
}`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest working with loops when you're required to check an array. It will make your code much cleaner and easier to read.

And now, to your first question: When your game begins, initalize the array with some characters that aren't neither 'X' nor 'O' (an empty string is also an option). Write a function which, after every turn, iterates over the entire array and look for that initialized value. If found, continue the game. If not found, change a boolean flag variable to indicate that the game is over and ended in a tie.

```
public bool isFull(char[] arr){
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++){
            if (arr[i, j] == initial_value){
                //If array in row i and column j is equal to the inital
                //value, return true.
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For your second problem, I would turn the action of placing a piece into the board into a separate function, which will check the flag I mentioned before. If the flag equals "true", don't allow the action to take place. I would recommend setting the flag in this manner:

```
public void placeGamePiece(Player p){
    if (gameEndFlag == false){
        //Do the turn
    }

    else
        Console.WriteLine("The game is over!"); //Or any other print 
                                                //function you are using.
}

public void startGame(){
    public bool gameEndFlag = false;
    //..........
    gameEndFlag = !isFull(GameBoard);
}
```

I hoped I answered all of your questions in a sufficient manner. Please let me know if you need any clarification about anything I've written here. If you haven't yet learned loops and functions I would recommend you learn those now.